# A simple Neural Network for learning the SIN function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to make a simple NN learn the sin function. I read a lot of tutorials online about neural networks, and here where am I now, this is my first ever NN:

```
from numpy import exp, array, random, dot, square, sin, pi, tanh

random.seed(1)

original_input = random.uniform(low = -2*pi, high = 2*pi, size = 50)
original_output = sin(original_input)

weight = 2 * random.random() - 1

for i in range(20000):
    output = tanh(dot(original_input, weight))
    d_output = 1 - square(output)
    error = original_output - output
    weight += dot(original_input.T, error * d_output)

GOAL = pi/4
print(tanh(GOAL * weight)) ##It should be 0.70710678118 but it's currently -1.0
```

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect the behaviour of `weight` to be as the loop iterates? Approximately what do you expect for the final value of `weight`? How does this compare to the results you actually observe? Separately: when you do `original_output = sin(original_input)`, how exactly do you believe you are specifying the angle (what units)? Now, what happened when you read the documentation? Does it match your expectation?

Comment: Separately: it appears that the "network" you're implementing consists of a single neuron (scalar value for the weight)? Are you really expecting such a network to be able to give you a result for the `sin` function accurate to several decimal places for an arbitrary angle? Why?

Comment: thank you @KarlKnechtel, the angle unit is in radian, I just fixed the code. so to find a solution I need to add more neurons?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think I'm near to finding a solution, but I need to ask a new question. thank you